# Attempt to invoke virtual method on Attempt to invoke virtual method android.widget.EditText.getText() on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Trying to get the value of Edit Text from a EditText inside the Dialog but getting this error again and again

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable
>   android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

I am inflating a view over another dialog it works fine but whenever I click ok in the dialog I keep getting the above error

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dimension_dialog, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getContext());
                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                        widthEditText = findViewById(R.id.Width);
                                        heightEditText = findViewById(R.id.Height);
                                        String width = widthEditText.getText().toString();
                                        String height = heightEditText.getText().toString();
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Values are: " + width + " " + height, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                        WIDTH=width
//                                        HEIGHT=height;
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

Comment: @Umar check my answer it will work

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Thanks again man!

Comment: @Umar accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing any view to the edittext change your code this way

```
 widthEditText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.Width);                                 
 heightEditText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need finding EditText from your dialog view like.

```
widthEditText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.Width);
heightEditText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
widthEditText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.Width);
heightEditText = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.Height);
```

you need to use your view in this way `promptView.findviewbyId`